# How to untrack a file in a subfolder

Tags: git

I have made a website with a mini game, and I am using git to keep track on my game development. Now I want to upload the site to heroku, which says that I need a git repository on the main folder. So it baisically looks like this.

```
myWebsite
    |- .git
    |- index.html
    |- miniGame
          |-  .git
          |-  index.html
          |-  myMiniGame.js
```

So the first `.git` is what is going to be pushed to heroku, the nested `.git` is the one I have for myself.

So what I want is heroku to never get a copy of my nested `.git` folder, for that I want the main git repo to not track the secondary git folder. My dream commands would be something like:

```
git add -A
git untrack miniGame/.git
git commit -m "something changed"
git push
```

But there is no `untrack` command, so How can I do this?

Comment: The command you want is `git rm`

So like `git rm ./miniGame/.git`

Comment: Yes, the output is `fatal: pathspec './NodeJS-Mario/.git' did not match any files`, and wiredly when I do a `git status` the miniGame shows up as a single file. Nothing inside it is listed

Comment: is .git a file, or is it a folder which is basically a git repository?  I'm guessing it's the latter, in which case it's probably seeing miniGame as a sub-module.  Do you have a .gitmodules file in the root of your source?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried with `.gitignore` file in the main git repo?
[.gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

If you already have files that you want to remove from repo
try with: `git rm --cached filename.ext`

Answer (score 0):

An easy option is to just include the name of the file you want to untrack in your .gitignore file. This will exclude it from git monitoring and you can go about without worrying about the file.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that if there is a `.git` folder (in a subfolder) it will be considered a submodule.

The best solution I have found is having a working copy, from where I develop the game and update my private git. Whenever I want to update the website, I copy the game folder into the websites folder and delete the `.git` folder from there. Then I commit and push to heroku.

Not the best solution, but fairly easy to do since I don't update the website every day.

- `.gitignore` did not work, probably because it is a submodules and not just any folder/file.